# Q couple questions on the CA Plumbing, Electrical Code RE: keep-out distances between gas, electric

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, gas

### General:

- Southern California area
- Residential
- Experience with HV and high pressure N2/CDA systems from my work, but not flammable high pressure gasses.

---

### Question 1:

Is there a minimum distance between black-pipe gas line and PVC electrical conduit when buried?

[image: gas-line-to-electrical-conduit]

Both the gas line ([CA Plumbing Code 1210.1.1](https://up.codes/viewer/california/ca-plumbing-code-2016/chapter/12/fuel-gas-piping#1210.1.1), [CA CoR Title 8, §536.a.2](https://www.dir.ca.gov/title8/536.html)) and the PVC electrical conduit ([CA Electrical Code, §300.5](https://www.fremont.gov/DocumentCenter/View/7159/BURIAL-DEPTHS-Electrical?bidId=)) need to be at least 18" deep, so I'd like to put them in the same 5" wide trench.

[Some people seem to think that there is no horizontal minimum distance.](https://www.electrical-contractor.net/forums/ubbthreads.php/topics/83887/Underground_How_close_Can_Gas_.html)

---

### Question 2:

What is the minimum distance between an electrical outlet and ...

#### a) a gas pipe?

There is no expectation of gas release, but the outlet is considered an ignition source.

[image: outlet-to-gas-line]

#### b) a gas value?

I'm assuming this case is different than (a) because there is potential for gas to be released.

[image: outlet-to-gas-value]

The only info I've found is specific to **gas meters**, and that says [3 feet from meter to electrical box front](https://inspectapedia.com/plumbing/Gas_Meter_Clearances.php).

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: I figured since both questions are related to keep-out distances, and will likely be found in the same section the the CA plumbing/electrical code, they should be asked as a single question.

Comment: I think you are referencing the wrong code. Instead of Title-8 (CaOSHA) on Compressed and Liquefied Natural Gas Systems, you should look in Title-24. Check the California Plumbing Code (specifically Chapter-12 Fuel Gas Piping). Also the California Mechanical Code and California Electrical Code...

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the OP to include a reference to CA Plumbing Code 1210.1.1.